# Trouble downloading table from Excel to BQ

Tags: sql, excel, google-bigquery

I'm trying to import a table in SQL using a .csv file from Excel but keep getting this error message, " Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered." I am completely stumped, tried Google and even YouTube for help and nothing. Thanks in advance!
I tried loading via Google Sheets and Excel, I've changed the file type to UTF-8 in Excel and still the same error code.

Comment: how exactly did you try to import the csv?

Comment: by creating a table and uploading as a CSV file

Comment: google offers multiple ways so i thought you tested one of them https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#sql

Comment: Thank you! I think it may be because my table has repeating data apparently

Comment: there is also a link for csv file upload with pythin, c# or whatever you like as  another possibilty https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-gcs-csv